# Switch on the Batterycase charger using iOS app

Tags: ios, mfi

We have designed one battery case for the iPhone for charging purpose. My requirement is I have to make an iOS app , using that app If I click on one button in the app , it should switch on the batterycase switch and starts charging the iPhone (Battery case connected to iPhone through the 30 pin or 8 Pin Connector). I would like to submit this app to AppStore.

1 . For this Shall I need to subscribe the MFi program?

2 . Will apple MFi Program approve this battery cases or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you will need to enroll the MFi program in order to get the mechanical drawings and to be able to purchase the connectors and authentication chips.

You will also have to design a (probably microcontroller based) driver circuit that will communicate with your app via USB or UART (BT would probably be an overkill for this purpose).

2) Probably yes - it just has to pass the tests. Maybe you will have to modify a thing or two. After you enroll the MFi you will get access to the documentation, guidelines etc...

The company that will be producing your product will also need an appropriate certificate.

3) You might encounter some technical problems since the connection diagram for charging devices and for devices with standalone power are somewhat different. And your device will find itself in both states (when charging and when 'idling').

Comment: Thank you @rokjarc. I hope it will be helpful.+1 for you .